# How does one go about setting up a mining pool?

Tags: monerodo-os, mining-setup, mining-pool-setup

There are already a number of mining pools out for Monero, are there instructions or software that people can use to set up their own mining pool?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[The Monerodo OS](http://nodebox.link/) from gingeropolous is a customized version of Ubuntu that includes Monero Core, Monero Pool Server, Nvidia mining software, various CPU mining software, and the MiniNodo Wallet server, already preinstalled and is easily configured with a simple text menu interface.

Step by step Monerodo OS [instructions](http://nodebox.link/ownbuild.html)

Alternatively this CryptoNote pool mining software is free and [open source](https://github.com/zone117x/node-cryptonote-pool)

```
git clone https://github.com/zone117x/node-cryptonote-pool.git pool
cd pool
npm update
```

Configuration instructions can be found [here](https://github.com/zone117x/node-cryptonote-pool#2-configuration)

Answer (score 6):

**Edit 11/19/2017:** another pool mining software has been [crowdfunded](https://forum.getmonero.org/9/work-in-progress/87114/release-of-new-updated-pool-software). Source and instructions can be found [here](https://github.com/Snipa22/nodejs-pool).

People with limited linux skills should try [Monerodo](https://moneroworld.com/#ownbuild), which is an ubuntu with a bunch of monero software pre-installed, including a pool software.

Otherwise, [zone117x node-cryptonote-pool](https://github.com/zone117x/node-cryptonote-pool) is a crowdfunded open source mining pool software and is the mostly used, including this popular [fork](https://github.com/clintar/node-cryptonote-pool)

There is also this relatively recent [software](https://github.com/sammy007/go-cryptonote-pool) written in Golang.

Comment: this one written in golang is only for solo mining? I couldn't find options like setting up automatic payments for miners or others useful services a pool offers

Comment: I don't know. The maintainer seems active, so i would suggest to open an issue.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed for solo mining