# How to set up a mining pool?

Tags: mining-pools, mining

What do I need to acquire in order to configure a mining pool? I want to make a "charity pool", where part of the pool fee will be donated to a charity voted upon by the miners. I really want to get this going. I need to know what resources I need and how much running a pool will cost for say 6 months. Please be specific! And if you want to get involved let me know, I could use help.

Answer (score 5):

If you have limited linux skills, i suggest you try [Monerodo](https://moneroworld.com/#ownbuild), which is an ubuntu with a bunch of monero software pre-installed, including a pool software.

Otherwise, you can start looking at [zone117x node-cryptonote-pool](https://github.com/zone117x/node-cryptonote-pool).

Either way, you will have to tweak the software to implement the "voting" part.

As to the cost, it can be as free as submitting a [PR](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-requests/) :)

It is not easy to attract miners. So if your goal is not financial (nothing wrong with that) it is probably the most efficient way.

Comment: Can you post this answer here instead? http://monero.stackexchange.com/q/602/7 Two answers to that question seems better than two questions that are close to duplicates