# Mining a custom coin based on Monero

Tags: mining, mining-pools, monero-forks

I am creating a custom coin based on Forking Monero.

Once the build process has been completed, how do I go about actually mining the coin?

Is it possible to modify XMRIG to do this?
https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im going to assume you've setup a mining pool for your "custom coin", just set the correct algo perimeters on xmrig and point it to your mining pool. Nothing needs to be modified in XMRig

Comment: For reference here, I am pasting this link for others:https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/602/how-does-one-go-about-setting-up-a-mining-pool

Comment: @Wesley Is setting up a mining pool the only way to mine a coin? Is there any way to mine directly without a mining pool?

Comment: Yes sure you can, it also depends what coins you plan on mining. If its your own coins, you can mine it using the wallet-cli (which uses your CPU). If you are the only one mining your coin then CPU mining it is best, there would be no point GPU mining it.