# Is it possible to solo mine Monero (XMR) using AMD and Nvidia GPUs in the same rig?

Tags: mining, mining-pools, gpu-mining, mining-hardware, solo-mining

I've been looking into this a lot over the past 2 days.

I have found ways to use AMD and Nvidia GPUs in a mining pool (XMR-stak), but I haven't been able to find any info on solo mining with both of these GPUs.

Does anyone know if its possible to do so? If so, is there a good guide?

Also, I'm using Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can solo mine using both cards if you use a miner like xmr-stak and point it to a pool that supports solo mining.

Comment: At this time, according to [http://moneropools.com/](http://moneropools.com/), the two only mining pools with solo option are broken/closed. Do you know an available pool with the solo option?

Comment: There are others. I don't want to be seen endorsing any particular pool, hence not posted links to any.

Comment: As an example, I just picked a random one from the moneropools site that did not have a pool tagged as supporting solo mining, went to the pool, looked up it's ports and found solo mining ports (monero.gt). moneropools does not list every pool or every pools options.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Monero.gt was not present when I checked, I have tried ten pools and no one has the solo option.

Comment: Additional info. In this way, you mine in solo through the pool so you must pay the pool fee.

Comment: Sure, but a LOT simpler for a noob than setting up a private pool.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the official Monero GUI wallet for solo mining](https://src.getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/solo_mine_GUI.html), but it uses only the CPU to mine.

There aren't specific applications for solo mining XMR through GPUs, but you can create and set up a local pool, then use it for solo mining with GPUs. More info on setting up your own pool available at [How does one go about setting up a mining pool?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/602/how-does-one-go-about-setting-up-a-mining-pool).

Comment: Hi. Do you know if there are any roundabout ways of solo mining with GPUs without using a private mining pool?

Comment: You can find some workaround here: [https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2083/solo-gpu-mining](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2083/solo-gpu-mining).

Comment: You do not need to setup your own pool. Most existing pools have a solo mining option.